# Call an activity on key back press

Tags: android

```
public class XXXX extends TabActivity{

TabHost tabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.XXXX);
    tabHost=getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, XXXX.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("XXXX").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, XXXX.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("XXXX").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
/*@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}*/
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Do what you want, forinstance:
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enter to key back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

I want to call home Activity on key back press.But it did not work.What i have done wrong i don't know.Please improve this answer.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: override on back press method and use Intent code there and remove super call    ... instead of onkeydown

Comment: i have done that but it didn't work.It goes to previous activity.

Comment: Use Flag with intent Clear Tast and  new TOP

Answer (score -1):

write this in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

pass `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` so it will clear all previous task and move to your HomeActivity